# For subspaces, if $N\subseteq M_1\cup\cdots\cup M_k$, then $N\subseteq M_i$ for some $i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a vector space $V$ over a field of characteristic $0$. If $M_1,\dots,M_k$ are proper subspaces of $V$, and $N$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $N\subseteq M_1\cup\cdots\cup M_k$, how can you tell $N\subseteq M_i$ for some $i$?

I was first trying to show it just in the case $N\subseteq M_1\cup M_2$, and hoping to extend it to finitely many $M_i$. If either of the $M_i$ contains the other, the claim follows, so I suppose neither $M_i$ contains the other.

In hopes of a contradiction, I suppose $N\not\subseteq M_1$ and $N\not\subseteq M_2$, Picking $x_1\in N\setminus M_1$ and $x_2\in N\setminus M_2$, I'd have $x_1+x_2\in N\subseteq M_1\cup M_2$. The only thing I could conclude was that actually $x_1,x_2\notin M_1$ and $x_1,x_2\notin M_2$, which seems like a dead end. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: @BryanUrízar Thanks, but I don't think that shows that $M_1\cup M_2$ is closed under $+$ since $x$ and $y$ are not arbitrary elements of $M_1\cup M_2$ since there is the condition that $x\in N\cap M_1$ and $y\in N\cap M_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this problem, you can try pointing out that if $N$ is not a subset of $M_1$, then it must be a subset of $M_2$. I'll give you some hints on this:

- Since $N \not \subset M_1$, then there exists some $x \in N \  \backslash \ M_1$.
- You should notice that, since $N = M_1 \cup M_2$ (i.e, every element in $N$ must belong to either $M_1$, or $M_2$), and we have that, $x \in N \  \backslash \ M_1$, so $x \in M_2$.
- Now, can you try showing that for all $n \in N$, $n$ must belong to $M_2$? **Hint**: Take their sum, and consider 2 cases. ;)

To show it holds not only for $k = 2$, but for any $k \in \mathbb{N} \ \backslash \ \{ 0 \}$, you can try using Proof by Induction. Case $k = 1$ is trivial, and $k = 2$ has already been done, can you continue from here? :)

Answer (score 6):

First show that $M_1\cup M_2$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $M_1\subseteq M_2$ or $M_2\subseteq M_1$.

This extends by induction to any finite number of subspaces: if $M=M_1\cup\ldots\cup M_k$ is a subspace of $V$ then there is some $i$ such that $M=M_i$.

Next show that if $N\subseteq M_1\cup\ldots\cup M_k$ then $N_i=N\cap M_i$ is a subspace of $V$, and therefore $N=N_1\cup\ldots\cup N_k$ and it is a subspace, so $N=N_i$ for some $i$, so $N\subseteq M_i$ as wanted.

Comment: Are you sure about your inductive step? The first statement also holds over finite fields, but how does the induction look like that it works only in characteristic 0?

Answer (score 5):

Recall that a [vector space over an infinite field is not a finite union of proper subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692376/a-question-on-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field?noredirect=1&lq=1). Since your scalar field has characteristic $0$, it is necessarily infinite, as it contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ for instance.

If $N\subseteq M_1\cup\cdots\cup M_k$, then 
$$
N=(N\cap M_1)\cup\cdots\cup(N\cap M_k).
$$
Viewing $N$ as a vector space in its own right, with $N\cap M_i$ subspaces of $N$, we see they cannot all be proper. So for some $i$, $N\cap M_i=N$, hence $N\subseteq M_i$.