# A real vector space $V$ is the union of three subspaces $P$, $Q$, $R$ of $V$. Prove that one of $P$,$Q$, $R$ is $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

[Closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/858576/389992)

Suppose that $V= P \ \cup Q \ \cup R  $. Leaving out the trivial case where one subspace contains the other one, we consider the following case:

$P-Q \neq \emptyset, Q-P \neq \emptyset,Q-R\neq \emptyset, R-Q\neq \emptyset,P-R\neq \emptyset, R-P\neq \emptyset $, i.e. each subspace contains elements, unavailable to the other ones.

We take $p \in P\setminus Q\cup R, q\in Q\setminus P\ \cup R$. Now, we consider the elements $p+q$ and $p+(-q)$. Evidently the two aforementioned elements can neither be in $P$ nor in $Q$ [ $\because   $ if in $P$, $(p+q)+(-p)=q \in P$, contradiction. Similar argument for the other one] . Since, the union of the three subspaces make up the entire vector space, both of them must be in $R$. Now, $(p+q)+(p+(-q))=2p\in R$. As $R$ is a real subspace, $\frac{1}{2}(2p)=p\in R$, a contradiction.

Therefore, one of them must be $V$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Compare with the proof at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414309/for-subspaces-if-n-subseteq-m-1-cup-cdots-cup-m-k-then-n-subseteq-m-i-for?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Almost similar.

Comment: Or see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692376/a-question-on-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field?noredirect=1&lq=1), this is well-known.

Comment: didn't read the rest of the answer on the first look, as the question differed.

Comment: We get $V\subseteq P\subseteq V$ by the duplicate, so equality (or with $Q$ or $R$). It is exactly the same question.

Comment: Thank You! Got the needed answer.