# How to prove if $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}$ is a subspace over $\mathbb{C}$ then $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}=V_{j}$ for some j?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V_{1},...,V_{n}$ are subspaces of the vector space $W$ (over $\mathbb{C}$). Prove: if  $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}$ is a subspace then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}=V_{j}$ for some $j$.

I know how to prove it when $n=2$, and when $n=3$ it becomes complicated. Is there an easy proof for this?

I read this question here

> [For subspaces, if $N\subseteq M_1\cup\cdots\cup M_k$, then $N\subseteq M_i$ for some $i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414309/for-subspaces-if-n-subseteq-m-1-cup-cdots-cup-m-k-then-n-subseteq-m-i-for)

But for those answers I can't figure out how they use induction. A comment for Asaf Karagila's answer makes sense:  The first statement also holds over finite fields, but how does the induction look like that it works only in characteristic $0$?